# Topic in Salt hydrolysis that I couldn't understand

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base

Salts can be made up of all combination S of ( SA ,WA) and (SB , WB) 
I understand how to deal with salts of strong acids with both strong and weak bases and also of strong bases with weak and strong acids but I want to understand how can we find the pH for the salts of weak acids and bases ? Also If you could explain the relationship of hydrolysis constant and the dissociation constants it would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Comment: You solve for the same equilibrium in the same way, except there are more variables and more constraints.

Comment: What constraints please elaborate

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75047/ph-of-ammonium-acetate-solution/99988?sfb=2#99988

Comment: The two equilibria are coupled because the hydronium ion concentration is the same in both, since it's the same species.