# What is the pH of a solution of iron acetate?

Tags: acid-base, ph

What is the pH of a $\ce{0.1 M}$ solution of $\ce{Fe(CH_3COO)_3}$? I'm not sure how to do this, as it would involve complicated mass balance equations, but I think I can apply the approximation $\ce{pH = \frac{1}{2}*(pKa(Fe^{3+}) + pKa(CH_3COOH)) = \frac{1}{2}*(4.76 + 2.22) = 3.48}$.

Is this approximation valid in this situation? If not, how would I correctly calculate the pH of the solution without solving complex mass balance equations?

Comment: Well the acetate will protonate making the pH go up. The iron can form hydroxides making the pH go down. Assume salt completely ionizes, and first assume that iron can be ignored. If iron is now above its solubility limit then you have to solve iron and acetate simultaneously.

Comment: Does your approximation completely ignore the _concentration_ of the solution?

Comment: PS - Iron has no pKa.

Comment: @MaxW Why not? The iron ion is a weak acid in water

Comment: Compare ammonium acetate, https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75047/ph-of-ammonium-acetate-solution

Comment: Well, not *iron* but its aquo complex to be precise...

Comment: Like $\ce{ [Fe(H2O)6]^3+ + H2O <=> [Fe(H2O)5(OH)]^2+ + H3O+}$

Comment: Ah.. yes. Thanks for the correction. Normally I'd just work the math for the "total" reacton, $\ce{Fe^{3+} + 3OH- -> Fe(OH)_3}$, but the iron complex would deprotonate in steps. Still bothers me to think of that being an "acid" since you can't have $\ce{Fe(H2O)_5(OH)Cl}$ as a salt.

Comment: Won't the iron precipitate as $\ce{FeOH3}$? You need to consider the $K_{sp}$ of the hydroxide as well.