# Finding a Mistake Calculating the pH of Ammonium Acetate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, equilibrium, ph

I'm trying to calculate the $\mathrm{pH}$ of a $\pu{0.10 M}$ solution of ammonium acetate, and I am struggling to find what mistake I am making within the following calculations:

We know that $\dfrac{[\ce{NH3}][\ce{H^{+}}]}{[\ce{NH4^{+}}]} = K_\mathrm{a} = 5.6 \times10^{-10}$, and that $\dfrac{[\ce{CH_3COOH}]}{[\ce{CH3COO^{-}}][\ce{H+}]} = K_\mathrm{b} = 5.56\times10^{-10}$, and so with an ICE chart, we can find that
$$\dfrac{x(x-y)}{0.1 - x}\approx\dfrac{x(x-y)}{0.1} = K_\mathrm{a}\text{, and }\dfrac{y}{(0.1-y)(x-y)}\approx\dfrac{y}{0.1(x-y)} = K_\mathrm{b}.$$

Solving these equations, we find that $x = \sqrt{0.1\times K_\mathrm{a}\times (0.1\times K_\mathrm{b} + 1)}\approx 4.48\times 10^{-6}$ and $y = x - \dfrac{0.1}{x}\times K_\mathrm{a} \approx 4.16 \times 10^{-16}$, so that $\mathrm{pH} = -\log{(x-y)} = 5.13$.

It should be that $\mathrm{pH} = 7.00$, and so where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Perhaps look here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/75047/79678.

Comment: What you have marked as the acetic acid Kb has about the correct value, but does not match the concentration expression on the left. That expression is equal to 1/Ka, while Kb=Kw/Ka.

Comment: As @Ed V pointed out in his comment, answer for this question can be found [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75047/ph-of-ammonium-acetate-solution).

Answer (score 2):

This was answered in the comments, but these second equilibrium expression should not actually be a $K_b$ value. Rather, it should be $1/K_a = 55600$. Using this value in the same calculations, we find that $x=5.5805\times 10^{-4}$ and $y = 5.5795\times 10^{-4}$, so that $\ce{pH} = -\log(x-y) = 7.00$.